# "No Add Button" for me to customize my WordPress with themes and pluggins

Tags: plugins, customization, themes

I have followed some of the answers I have found  concerning my problem but to No avail.
I have tried the formula that deals with the Dashboard process

I have also tried the other formula that
You would have to login to Cpanel,go to > file manager, click to edit> wp-config. Php, located
define('DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT',TRUE) and then change the "TRUE" there to False
and also Locate

Define ('DISALLOW_FILE_MODS', TRUE) and change that "TRUE" as well  to False

The thing is that I can only fine

define ('wp_DEBUG', False);

define ('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE',true);
define ('MULTISITE', true);

define (SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL',false

These are the only content with true and false there. please Do I have to change any true to false or any False to true to make the ADD BUTTON available for themes and pluggins

Answer (score 3):

Are you using wp multisite? If yes, you can add themes and plugins only from multisite dashboard, and not from site dashboard